# how to use for loop in powershell to take multiple variable values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a network share and Set ACL permission, it works perfect for 1 folder but i would like to create the same thing for 1 more folder, i just do not want to repeat the code.

following is my working code for 1 folder, i will also put the path of other folder

```
$MediaFoler_Security = 'C:\Projects\MediaContent'
$acl = Get-Acl $MediaFoler_Security
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS","FullControl",   
"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $MediaFoler_Security $acl
```

Here is my other folder path

```
$DeployFolder_Security = 'C:\Projects\Deployments'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
$folders = "C:\Projects\Mediacontent","C:\Projects\Deployments"

foreach($folder in $folders){

$acl = Get-Acl $folder
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS","FullControl",   
"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $folder $acl

}
```

Comment: your code works perfect, at the moment i only have 1 user 'IIS_IUSRS', how can i add 'administrators' as well along with IIS_IUSRS without having to add an extra line,

Comment: you cant, add the extra lines for a second access rule in the loop

Comment: so is there any way i can add IIS_IUSRS and administrator in 1 go

Comment: maybe, but i cant think of one right now. also why not just add another 2 lines? if you want the logic part of your script to be organized and clean then create functions instead of doing the work in the logic part

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a function:

```powershell
function my-acl($path) {
  $acl = Get-Acl $path
  $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS","FullControl",   
  "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
  $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
  Set-Acl $path $acl
}
```

And call like:

```powershell
my-acl 'C:\Projects\MediaContent'
my-acl 'C:\Projects\Deployments'
```

Or:

```powershell
$dirs = @('C:\Projects\MediaContent','C:\Projects\Deployments')
$dirs | % { my-acl $_ }
```

Comment: More, look into Advanced Functions `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`. `[CmdletBinding()]` gives you -Verbose, -WhatIf and -Confirm for free - `Get-Help about_functions_CmdletBinding`